# Prove that if $z ∈ C$ satisfies that $| z | = 2$, then there exists $b ∈ R$ such that $ \frac{2+z}{2-z} = bi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that if $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies that $| z | = 2$, then there exists $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \dfrac{2+z}{2-z} = bi$.

I did the following

Let $z=a+bi$

$\dfrac{2+a+ib}{2-a-ib} = \dfrac{(2+a+ib)(2-a+ib)}{(2-a)^2+b^2} = \dfrac{1+2bi}{3-2a}$

Because $| z | = 2 \implies 4= a^2+b^2$

Comment: When dealing with algebraic problems in the complex numbers, like this one, it is depressingly rare that substituting in $a + bi$ is the best way to go. This is something I learned after trying to do exactly that a lot of times, and never getting anywhere with it. It is better to just learn to deal with the complex numbers directly.

Comment: @Arthur Here, for new students, I'm going to have to moderately disagree.  Although descending to Cartesian coordinates does forgo elegance, it still often gets the job done.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming $z\neq \pm 2$ in this solution.

Draw the circle with radius $2$ centered at the origin in the complex plane. Note that $z$ and $-z$ are diametrically opposite in this circle.

$2-z$ is the vector that goes from $z$ to $2$, and $2+z$ is the vector that goes from $-z$ to $2$. By [Thales' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), these are orthogonal. Thus their ratio as complex numbers must be purely imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{2+2e^{i\theta}}{2-2e^{i\theta}} = i\;\frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the expression

\begin{equation}
\frac{2 + z}{2 - z}
\end{equation}
which we want to show is purely imaginary. Since we know something about the modulus of $z$, namely $|z|=\sqrt{zz^*}=2$, let us multiply by the complex conjugate of $z$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{2z^* + zz^*}{2z^* - zz^*}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{2z^* + 4}{2z^* - 4}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{z^* + 2}{z^* - 2} = \frac{2+z}{2-z}
\end{equation}

Rewriting again
\begin{equation}
\frac{z^* + 2}{z^* - 2} = -\frac{z+2}{z-2}
\end{equation}

But complex conjugation distributes over well-defined fractions ($z^* \neq 2$),
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{z + 2}{z - 2}\right)^* = -\frac{z+2}{z-2}
\end{equation}
Which states that for some complex number $h\equiv \frac{z+2}{z-2}$,

$h^* = -h$
Which implies that $h$ itself is purely imaginary.

To see why, $h = A+Bi$ for some $A,B \in \mathbb{C}$, and substituting into the above equation reveals: $A-Bi = -A-Bi \rightarrow A=-A \rightarrow A=0,B$ is a free parameter.

In summary, $h = \frac{2+z}{2-z} = Bi$ for some $B \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach

Although converting to Cartesian coordinates often leads nowhere, and certainly will not lead to an elegant solution, it (still) often gets the job done.

Let $z = x + iy$. 
Without loss of generality, $z = (x + iy) \neq (2 + i[0])$, else the LHS fraction is undefined, since you can't divide by $(0)$.

Since $|z| = 2, x^2 + y^2 = 4.$

$\displaystyle \frac{2 + z}{2 - z} = 
\frac{(2 + x) + i(y)}{(2 - x) - i(y)}
\times \frac{(2 - x) + i(y)}{(2 - x) + i(y)}$

$\displaystyle
= \frac{(4 - x^2 - y^2) + i(4)}{(4 - 4x + x^2 + y^2) + i(0)}
= \frac{i(4)}{8 - 4x}.$

Again, since $(x + iy) \neq (2 + i[0])$ and yet $|z| = 2$, you know that you can't have $x = 2$.

Therefore, in the above fraction, the denominator is a non-zero real number and the numerator is an imaginary number.  Therefore, the fraction represents an imaginary number.

This answer employed the common technique of multiplying both the denominator and the numerator by the complex conjugate of the denominator.  This automatically converts the denominator to a real number, which allow you to focus exclusively on the numerator.

For example:

$\displaystyle \frac{a + ib}{c + id} \times \frac{c - id}{c - id} = \frac{(ac + bd) + i(bc - ad)}{c^2 + d^2}.$